# Obtaining Current From Quantum State of 3d, assumed hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

So I've been banging my head against this problem for a while and I genuinely have no clue how my answer is differing than the one provided to me and while I'm not usually the type to ask such a thing, I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.
So here's what I did:

First thing's first, a state of 3d gives us $n=3, and\:l=2$ This is nice since it's kinda all we have/should need. We also know that $\mu=I\cdot A$ where $I$ is the current in amps, $A$ is the area of the circle that the orbit of the electron creates and $\mu$ is our magnetic moment. Cool, we also know that $\mu=\mu_B\sqrt{l\left(l+1\right)}$ ($\mu_B$ is the Bhor Magneton, around $9.3\cdot10^{-24} \: J/T$) and because we have a hydrogen atom we also have that our radius can be found with $r_n=n^2a_0$ where $n$ is our principal number and $a_0$ is the base radius of hydrogen (something like $0.529165899$ angstroms). This gives us a radius of $9a_0$

So we mash all these together and plug in to find $I$ right?

$$I=\frac{\mu }{A}=\frac{\mu _B\sqrt{l\left(l+1\right)}}{\pi r^2}=\frac{\mu _B\sqrt{2\left(2+1\right)}}{\pi \cdot \left(3^2\cdot a_0\right)^2}=~3.18801\cdot 10^{-5}A$$

Except, it seems the answer is NOT this, instead, it's apparently supposed to be $4.43\cdot 10^{-7}A$. So either the book is wrong (seeming more and more plausible) or I'm wrong, and I really want to know where I screwed up. I AM NOT ASKING FOR THE SOLUTION. What's the point of learning then? All I need to know is what step I've missed so I can put the puzzle together myself.

Thanks so much anyone who comes to my aid.

Edit: I've realized that I should make people aware that we are kinda just assuming that the Bohr model of perfect circles is "true" or at least true enough for the electron to mimic a current in a wire loop while orbiting the nucleus. It's not true and I'm aware, this idea is more for an introduction in the electromagnetic mechanics that go on with atoms (really just hydrogen atoms). The main thing this was for was to introduce a very general idea of the Zeeman effect and similar phenomenon. We are also ignoring spin here since this question is being asked in the chapter before it was explained so I'm assuming I'm not supposed to worry about it.

Comment: Your reasoning and computation is not too bad; if the answer key is so far off, it is likely that it is using a totally different model. This computation is of no practical use: to get the proper behaviour, you have to understand quantum theory, and then there is no simple loop whereby a constant current I can be defined with a constant loop radius r. I would even be worried about whether the answer key is even correct or not.

Comment: Ah, well it's a good thing you pointed that out. The "simple loop" thing was more to introduce us to the idea of electromagnetic effects that arise from the atomic model. This is modern physics and not a dedicated QM class, and so lacking more rigorous mathematics, we make do. That being said sometimes the book is wrong, often times it's not but it's free and easy to read so... worth it overall. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: The value in the answer key is 100 times smaller than what you calculated (and I verified that your calculation value is ok). This means that something completely different is being used, and I don't know how to help you.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the atom is in a constant magnetic field right? No direction is given on this field so we're just assuming the atom is aligned already, there's no change in flux so idk either man, thanks for trying though